# Python tkinter printing unexpected newlines

Tags: python, tkinter, newline

Tkinter is adding newlines every 30 seconds:

[Unwanted newlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYEGe.png)

I'm running this in windows CMD.

I wrote a simple program to test this with a single `askopenfilename()` call in there.

When I click the browse button, it adds a newline, then after I choose the file and click begin, it adds a newline every 30 seconds while the program is "running":

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import time

def input1():
    input1_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    input1_entry.delete(1, tk.END)  # Remove current text in entry
    input1_entry.insert(0, input1_path)  # Insert the 'path'
    
#returns file paths for the input files and output directory
def begin():
    global inputFileName
    inputFileName = input1_entry.get()
    master.destroy()
    
master = tk.Tk()
master.title('Omega NExT Archive Plotter')
one_frame = tk.Frame(master)
two_frame = tk.Frame(master)
line1 = tk.Frame(master, height=1, width=400, bg="grey80", relief='groove')
input1_path = tk.Label(one_frame, text="Archive File Input:")
input1_entry = tk.Entry(one_frame, text="", width=60)
browse1 = tk.Button(one_frame, text="Browse", command=input1)
begin_button = tk.Button(two_frame, text='Begin!', command=begin)
one_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP)
line1.pack(pady=10)
two_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
input1_path.pack()
input1_entry.pack()
browse1.pack(pady=10)
begin_button.pack(pady=20, fill=tk.X)
master.mainloop()


time.sleep(1000000)
```

This happens on some computers, but not others. I don't get it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. But why do you call `time.sleep(1000000)` at the end?

Comment: I do it to keep the program running so you can watch a newline appear every 30 seconds. I don't understand how tkinter is doing stuff after it's supposed to be "destroyed".